# How to Avoid Conditionals in Loops

Tags: performance, optimization, fortran, fortran90

In this [link](http://jblevins.org/log/efficient-code), the author gives an example as

```
subroutine threshold(a, thresh, ic)
  real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: a
  real, intent(in) :: thresh
  integer, intent(out) :: ic
  real :: tt
  integer :: n

  ic = 0
  tt = 0.d0
  n = size(a)
  do j = 1, n
     tt = tt + a(j) * a(j)
     if (sqrt(tt) >= thresh) then
        ic = j
        return
     end if
  end do
end subroutine threshold
```

and the author commented this code as

> An alternative approach, which would allow for many optimizations
>   (loop unrolling, CPU pipelining, less time spent evaluating the
>   conditional) would involve adding tt in blocks (e.g., blocks of size
>   128) and checking the conditional after each block. When it the
>   condition is met, the last block can be repeated to determine the
>   value of ic.

**What does it mean? loop unrolling? CPU pipelining? adding `tt` in blocks?**

How to optimize the code as the author say?

Comment: Well, I think the first thing to do is to replace "sqrt(tt) >= thresh" to "tt >= thresh_sq" (where thresh_sq = thresh**2 is prepared before entering the loop)...

Comment: @roygvib this is clever!+1

Comment: I took the liberty to correct the code such that it can actually compile ;-)

Comment: another possible (and simple)  optimization to consider here is precomputing a length `n` array of the calculated results (in this example case it would be one line like `a2=a**2` ), then your loop will just contain the addition and conditional. Of course the effectiveness of this  this depends on a lot of things like the size of n and the likelihood of the conditional being satisfied early in the loop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the loop is performed in **chunks/blocks** that fit into the CPU cache you will reduce the number of cache misses, and consequently the number of cache lines retrieved from memory. This increases the performance on all loops that are limited by memory operations. 
If the corresponding block size is `BLOCKSIZE`, this is achieved by

```
do j = 1, n, BLOCKSIZE
   do jj = j, j+BLOCKSIZE-1 
      tt = tt + a(jj) * a(jj)
   end do
end do
```

This, however, will leave a remainder that is not treated in the main loop. To illustrate this, consider an array of length `1000`. The first seven chunks (1--896) are covered in the loop, but the eighth one (897--1024) is not. Therefore, another loop for the remainder is required:

```
do j=(n/BLOCKSIZE)*BLOCKSIZE,n
   ! ...
enddo
```

While it makes little sense to remove the conditional from the remainder loop, it can be performed in the outer loop of the blocked main loop. 
As now no branches occur in the inner loop, aggressive optimizations might be applicable then.
However, this limits the "accuracy" of the determined position to the blocks. To get to an element-wise accuracy, you have to repeat the calculation.

Here is the complete code:

```
subroutine threshold_block(a, thresh, ic)
  implicit none
  real, dimension(:), intent(in) :: a
  real, intent(in) :: thresh
  integer, intent(out) :: ic
  real :: tt, tt_bak, thresh_sqr
  integer :: n, j, jj
  integer,parameter :: BLOCKSIZE = 128

  ic = 0
  tt = 0.d0
  thresh_sqr = thresh**2
  n = size(a)
  ! Perform the loop in chunks of BLOCKSIZE
  do j = 1, n, BLOCKSIZE
     tt_bak = tt
     do jj = j, j+BLOCKSIZE-1 
        tt = tt + a(jj) * a(jj)
     end do
     ! Perform the check on the block level
     if (tt >= thresh_sqr) then
        ! If the threshold is reached, repeat the last block 
        ! to determine the last position
        tt = tt_bak
        do jj = j, j+BLOCKSIZE-1 
           tt = tt + a(jj) * a(jj)
           if (tt >= thresh_sqr) then
              ic = jj
              return
           end if
        end do
     end if
  end do

  ! Remainder is treated element-wise
  do j=(n/BLOCKSIZE)*BLOCKSIZE,n
     tt = tt + a(j) * a(j)
     if (tt >= thresh_sqr) then
        ic = j
        return
     end if
  end do 
end subroutine threshold_block
```

Please note that the compilers are nowadays very good in creating blocked loops in combination with other optimizations. In my experience it is quite difficult to get a better performance out of such simple loops by manually tweaking it.
Loop blocking is enabled in `gfortran` with the compiler option `-floop-block`.

---

**Loop unrolling** can be done manually, but should be left to the compiler. The idea is to manually perform a loop in blocks and instead of a second loop as shown above, perform the operations by duplicating the code. Here is an example for the inner loop as given above, for a loop unrolling of factor four:

```
do jj = j, j+BLOCKSIZE-1,4
   tt = tt + a(jj)   * a(jj)
   tt = tt + a(jj+1) * a(jj+1)
   tt = tt + a(jj+2) * a(jj+2)
   tt = tt + a(jj+3) * a(jj+3)
end do
```

Here, no remainder can occur if `BLOCKSIZE` is a multiple of `4`. You can probably shave off a few operations in here ;-)
The `gfortran` compiler option to enable this is `-funroll-loops`

---

As far as I know, **CPU Pipelining** ([Instruction Pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining)) cannot be enforced manually in Fortran. This task is up to the compiler.

Pipelining sets up a pipe of instructions. You feed the complete array into that pipe and, after the wind-up phase, you will get a result with each clock cycle. This drastically increases the throughput. 
However, branches are difficult (impossible?) to treat in pipes, and the array should be long enough that the time required for setting up the pipe, wind-up, and wind-down phase are compensated.

Comment: nice explanation. It should be emphasized that you should only go to such efforts if you have profiled the code and determined that particular loop is a critical bottleneck.  There is a clear drawback in terms of readability/maintenance and chance of introducing errors if you routinely write code like that.

Comment: @agentp I agree, and even then the block size, unrolling factor, and especially the pipelining is highly depending on the machine your code is executed on. Unless you know exactly what you are doing, the compiler will probably do a better job than you.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt Very clear explanation! I learned a lot. But as I tested, the modified version is only a slightly faster than original version.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt for 100000000 array, I tried `ifort /fast` for maximum optimization, the non-block version takes 1.494s, and block version takes 1.447s. If we use `ifort /Od` to disable all optimization, then non-block version takes 4.28s, and block version takes 4.43s, so block is actually slower than non-block with no optimization